# Como atender uma chamada freeswitch

Tags: java

Estou utilizando `uuid_answer`, `<uuid>`, para atendimento da chamada mas sem sucesso. Alguém sabe outra forma de atender uma chamada no `freeswitch`?

Comment: Desculpe-me a minha ignorância, mas o que é `freeswitch`? Seria [isso aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeSWITCH)? Pergunto isso porque suspeito fortemente que as tags precisam ser editadas.

Comment: Isso mesmo Victor